# create column with data from another table

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a table 1 with data from users, such as:

- Name;
- UserId;
- Email

I have a table 2 with data about referrals, such as:

- ReferrerId;
- ReferredId;

Now, let's say that ReferrerId = 84

84 is the UserId of Bob.

I want to create a column in table 2 that shows the email from Bob.

- ReferrerId: 84
- ReferrerEmail: bob@email.com

Is it possible to do this in phpmyadmin?

I tried INSERT INTO but my knowledge isn't that solid to create a functional query for this occasion.

Comment: When you want to add a column to a table, you need to change the table (ALTER TABLE), and use (ADD COLUMN), so: `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ......`  (for the complete syntax see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: When you want/need to add a ROW, you need: `INSERT INTO ....` (for the complete syntax see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html )

Comment: It seem the words in your question are confusing (these words: "I want to create a column in table 2 that shows the email from Bob.".  This is confusing because a column has as many values as there are records in that table )

Comment: Hello Luuk, thank you for your replies. I'm taking my time to take a look at them.

Comment: is my sintax correct?

INSERT INTO tbl_2
SELECT userEmail FROM tbl_1
WHERE 
tbl_1.userId = tbl_2.referrerId;

Comment: Try it. When it is not correct your will get an error, and noting else will happen. When it is correct you will get a new record in `tbl_2`.   (For getting  a course in SQL (or MySQL) you should do some research, there are plenty of website who share that info... Like, just to mention 1 (maybe not the best, but a *known* one): https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ )

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the user information (including email address) in table1, you should not duplicate that information in table2. In fact, it looks like your data is pretty well [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) now, which is a good thing.

Instead of adding the user's email address to table2, you should build queries to leverage the power of a database to retrieve the information you need. For instance, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d87e0/6/0

A query like

```
SELECT table1.Email, table2.ReferrerId 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.UserID=table2.ReferrerId;
```

or

```
SELECT table1.Email, table2.ReferrerId 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.UserID=table2.ReferrerId;
```

Are likely to get you started on the right path.